# C program crashes after 2 reallocs

Tags: c, realloc

I'm trying to write a small C program, but it crashes once I try to realloc with new_size being 20. Every value for new_size (in the function reallocate_buffer) under 20 works perfectly. I don't understand what's happening. This is my code.

```
char* reallocate_buffer(char* buffer, unsigned new_size)
{
    if (!buffer)
    {
        printf("Invallid buffer pointer given!\n");
        printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
        getchar();
        exit(2);
    }
    realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * new_size);
    printf("Realloc is done...\n");
    if (!buffer)
    {
        printf("Couldn't increase buffer size! Maybe out of memory?\n");
        printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    return buffer;
}

char* read_input(int* text_length)
{
    unsigned bufsize = BUFFER_SIZE;
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
    char c;
    unsigned done = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        printf("C is now %d\n", c);
        buffer[done] = c;
        done += 1;

        if (done == bufsize)
        {
            printf("Reallocating...\n");
            printf("Buffer size was now: %d\n", bufsize);
            bufsize += 5;
            buffer = reallocate_buffer(buffer, bufsize);
            printf("Buffer size is now: %d\n", bufsize);
        }
    }

    /* Now increase size once more if necessary to place the \0 character */
    if (bufsize == done)
    {
        printf("Reallocing once more...\n");
        bufsize++;
        reallocate_buffer(buffer, bufsize);
    }

    buffer[done] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    printf("Please provide input:\n");
    int line_size;
    char* word = read_input(&line_size);
    printf("You provided:\n%s\n", word);
    printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
    getchar();
    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and it says" - What? However, RTFM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to receive the address of reallocated buffer as the return value like

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * new_size);
```

Comment: That's indeed the solution! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Never do this. If `realloc()` fails and you will not exit from the program yet, you just caused a memory leak. Also `sizeof(char)` is very unnecessary.

Comment: @iharob Are the `printf()` and `getchar()` after `realloc()` in the original code bad things?

Comment: I mean `buffer = realloc(buffer, new_size);` is a very bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use `realloc()` is

```
void *temp;
temp = realloc(buffer, new_size); // Note that: sizeof(char) == 1 ALWAYS
if (temp == NULL)
    handle_allocation_error_or_exit(); // `buffer' is still valid here
else
    buffer = temp;
```

The way you have **it does not store the returned pointer**. You should bear in mind that `realloc()` might actually `free()` the pointer and reallocate new memory. But only if it can successfully do so.

Not using a temporary pointer has issues related to it, a few to mention

1. You cannot `free()` the old pointer because you overwrite it with `NULL`
2. For the same reason, now you will not have access to the data that was previously in the memory pointed to by buffer, you might need it to recover, or to write it to permanent storage or whatever, but you would lose reference to it if `realloc()` fails.

It's true that it's quite hard to make `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()` fail when you are using a system with +8GB of RAM, but it's not impossible. In my case, sometimes I am running a Video Conference program and sharing a Windows 10 quemu virtual machine with 2GB of memory and at the same time using the web browser, some IDE like Android Studio (which eats a lot of memory) + Android Emulator (again qemu). You can be surprised as to how quickly the RAM is consumed, in this situation the program might fail at `realloc()` and you could have lost some important data.

Answer (score -1):

Let's review it backward:

In C, in order for a function to change an argument, it has to receive that argument as a pointer.

But what happens if that argument is a pointer? the function has to get that pointer as a pointer to pointer.

As you noticed, `realloc` doesn't get the pointer as `void**` but as a `void*`, meanning it can not change that pointer to point to the new location of the memory.

So logically, the expression
`realloc(ptr,new_size);` 
is pointless, the memory address has being changed, but not the pointer.

this is why `realloc` returns the new address as `void*`, and you have to update the original pointer:

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, new_size);
```

P.S.
I'm not sure using visual studio as a C IDE is the best idea.

Comment: Visual Studio is indeed not the best IDE, but we are obligated to use it by our teacher ;)

Comment: It is extremly good IDE, for C++ and C# , not C, in my opinion

Comment: I think Visual Studio is not good for learning C because it has many confusing features such as accepting `void main()` and rejecting using `scanf()`, etc.

Comment: It simply was built as a C++ IDE with C++ compiler, that's it. microsoft won't spend resources to develop real support in C, although I can understand them